# How to run code in ApiController after AuthenticationFilter, before Action?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to implement an IAuthenticationFilter (the **Web Api 2** flavour, *not* the MVC flavour) and I'm struggling with the order the code is executed. I would have expected the Authentication filter to be run before any controller-based stuff, so that I could set the appropriate principal and then load the relevant user data from my DbContext in some kind of base ApiController.

This is the flow I'm after:

```
AuthenticationFilter ==> BaseController ==> Controller/Action
```

1. **AuthenticationFilter:-** Test Authorization header and set the principal if all is well.
2. **BaseController:-** Use the principal to find the full User record in database and assign it to a `protected` property.
3. **Controller/action:-** Complete action as normal, has access to the
   user record as set in the BaseController.

I'm not sure where to put the code in a BaseController in order to have it execute *after* the authentication filter, but *before* the resolved controller/action.

**Question**

So my question is two-fold: Am I going about this the wrong way? If not, how should I be performing step 2?

Comment: Get the full user record in the action as normal using the principal that was set in the `AuthenticationFilter`. You can retrieve it in a protected method that the action calls early when invoked.

Comment: Can you show some code to give an example of `BaseController` and intended use in Controller/action

Comment: @Nkosi thanks, that would definitely work, but I'm hoping to avoid the need to do it in every action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. In my BaseController I made a protected property called LoggedInUser, and made a special getter:

```
private User _loggedInUser;
protected User LoggedInUser
{
    get
    {
        if (_loggedInUser != null) return _loggedInUser;

        var identity = RequestContext.Principal.Identity;
        var userId = identity.GetUserId();

        _loggedInUser = MyDbContext.Users.Find(userId);
        return _loggedInUser;
    }
}
```

This allowed me to keep the code in one place, the BaseController, while still allowing me to defer the attempt to fetch the user until after the authentication has taken place.

Comment: Was in the middle of writing my answer when you provided yours. :) You can use the controller's `User` instead of `RequestContext` as well